# Can Fortify Restoration go too far?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have found that if you use the Fortify Restoration glitch too much you will end up unable to talk to anyone. Why is this?

If it can be fixed on the PS3 please tell me how.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that using the glitch "too far" can cause the game to misbehave. Exactly what causes it I am not sure of, but I am quite sure the only solution was to simply load a save created before using the glitch.

I can add that using it too much is pointless, unless you just wanna see big numbers on enchanted weapons and armor. Damage negating effects like armor and spell resist usually have a cap, and "infinite mana" can be achieved without using the glitch anyway.

By using enchanted gear and potions to fortify smithing, as well as a high enough smithing level + max enchanting, should grant you the ability to achieve both good damage negating and damage output even on legendary without any glitch. It just takes time.

Comment: I have did that a bunch of times it doesnt help

Comment: Exactly what in my post have you tried?

Comment: YES I AM TOTALLY GLITCHED

Comment: Umm... It is on PS3

Comment: Oh, yes. of course. My bad...